# "have too much to do" vs "have to do too much"

Tags: sentence-construction

> I **have too much to do** here. ["too" = very]
>
> I **have to do** here **too much**. ["too" = more than "I want"]

As I understand it, these sentences have the different meaning. The first sentence says that there is a lot of work to do. The second sentence says that "I must do" more than "I want". Right?

The above mentioned means also that if there is a word (or some words) between "have" & "to do", we can't consider it as "have to do" + that word (or those words). Am I right?

Comment: The second one does not sound at all idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have too much to do here** is idiomatic but your second sentence is not.

"I have to do homework": means I **must** do it.
"I have homework to do" means it exists and needs to be done.

There is more urgency or compulsion in the first than the second.